# Error analysis for 4th order Runge-Kutta

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, numerical-methods, approximation, runge-kutta-methods

Could anyone explain to me how to reduce the error propagated by using Runge-Kutta of order 4? Or can anyone give me a nice reference to it?

Comment: Google or Wikipedia are often good places to start. Is that not working for you?

Comment: What error do you want to reduce? Most of the errors in RK4 are unavoidable. Usually the (optimal-for-floating-point) step size is so large resp. the number of steps so small that cancellation while adding a small increment to a large number is not a problem (one can get improvements there in order 2 methods).